# Why does the potential difference in a quartz crystal change?

Tags: voltage

Please help me out here... If the potential difference at a mid-point between two opposite charges of the same magnitude "Q" is = 0V.. then how does the potential difference in a quartz crystal change, when it's expanding evenly on either sides of the charges?
Perhaps I may not have understood the whole concept...[image]

Comment: You're making too much of this "mid-point potential", it is just a **reference point** and actually not even needed. When the mid point is set to 0 V (zero Volts) then you can view the crystal as two identical but separate crystals. Both will generate a voltage under stress. The way you connect the two crystals will determine what the voltage across both will be, similar to two batteries in series.

Comment: When quartz crystals are stressed, the electron orbitals change slightly, uniformly, and charges migrate to extremes of the physical structure.